# Does SELECT automatically merge columns with the same column names?

Tags: sql, select, join

I am running the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerID ASC;
```

on some public tables at https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in. Both of the `Customers` and `Orders` tables contain a column called `CustomerID`. Part of the output is shown below
(where `NULL` values can be found in the`CustomerID` column): 
[image]

I am assuming that the `SELECT` statement is executed on an intermediate virtual table where both `Customers.CustomerID` and `Orders.CustomerID` exist.

My questions are the following:

1. How do these two columns (`Customers.CustomerID` and `Orders.CustomerID`) end up as single one (`CustomerID`) shown in the output?
2. Why are there `NULL` values in the output?

---

Updates:

The output shown above was from Chrome. Per @SQLChao's suggestion, I run the same query on Firefox, and the output is shown below (where both `Customers.CustomerID` and `Orders.CustomerID` exist):
[image]

Comment: When I run your query in the link provided I do not get the same results. The first Customer Alfreds doesn't have a null CustomerID. Also CustomerID shows up twice as it should.

Comment: They are not the same column, and in reality (SQL Server, MySQL, etc) won't be shown as one.

Comment: Update to my comment earlier. I ran this in Chrome and was able to get the same results you linked too. When run in Firefox I get different results that look correct to me.

Comment: You are getting NULL because your LEFT JOIN means this: give me all the records from Customers table, and find whatever you can match from Orders table, and if there was no match, give me NULL

Comment: @SQLChao Thanks! I run the same query on Firefox and it looks correct as well. Don't know why it didn't work on Chrome though.

Comment: This looks like behavior that only exists in the bizarro world of w3schools. If you were to run this `Select *` on any RDBMS that isn't in bizarro world, you would get two columns.